# object array not showing all variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have the code shown below.
My problem is: the part `console.log(obj)` is saying that `Object {InternalNumber = 22 }` and leaving out all the other variables. 
I am expecting it to say:

`Object { Id = someID, ParameterId="someParaId", InternalNumber = someNr, value="someValue"}`

What might be wrong?

If you haven't noticed... I am saving the object to localStorage, and then retrieving it from there.

```
function getModel() {

    var model = {
        Id: '',
        ParameterId: '',
        InternalNumber: '',
        Value: ''
    }

    return model;
}

function saveObjectToLocal() {
    model = getModel();

    model.Id = $(this).find(':input[name$=Id]').val();
    model.ParameterId = $(this).attr('id');
    model.InternalNumber = currentParcel.children('#viewModel_InternalNumber').val();
    model.Value = $(this).find(':input[name$=Value]').val();

    localStorage.setItem("model", JSON.stringify(model));        
}

function getObjectFromLocalAndInsertInFields() {
    obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("model"));
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: What do `localStorage.getItem("model")` and `JSON.stringify(model)` return?

Comment: They both return "{"InternalNumber":"22"}"

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling `saveObjectToLocal` function. $(this) inside of that function is probably not matching anything because "this" is probably the global (window) object, and DOM elements aren't matched within the window object.

To see what I'm talking about. Run:

```
$(this);
$(this).find("input");
$(this).find("input").attr("id");
```

from your console. The first output will be length 1 of just window, the second would be an empty jQuery object, and the third would be undefined.

Calling .val() and .attr on an empty jQuery list would be undefined and therefore not serialized to JSON. InternalNumber is serialized because currentParcel.children is giving a match. You need to fix the $(this) selectors.

Comment: This is indeed the answer. The solution was (like you referred) to get the control by id instead of $(this)

Answer (score 0):

Json stringify function will exclude attributes with undefined value, so check first if the missing attributes have values